# How to hide the second element in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a html look like this

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <p></p> //this can be any tag like <ul></ul> or <h1></h1>...
    <ul></ul> //this can be any tag like <p></p> or <h1></h1>...
    <div></div> //this too
</div>
```

I want to apply `display:none` to the second element in #mainDiv (in this case it's `<ul></ul>` ) so that it would be hidden.

How could I achieve it?

Comment: Look into CSS's :nth-child(2) selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector

```css
#mainDiv :nth-child(2) {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv">
  <p>First is a Paragraph </p>
  <ul>
    <li>Second element is an UL</li>
  </ul>
  <div>Third is a div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the universal selector is not mandatory

Comment: @mplungjan Yes I changed my vote so that this thread would be more on point.

Answer (score 1):

Use [nth child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector with [universal selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Type_Class_and_ID_Selectors#the_universal_selector) `*`

```css
#mainDiv * {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

#mainDiv *:nth-child(2) {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv">
    <p></p> //this can be any tag like <ul></ul> or <h1></h1>...
    <ul></ul> //this can be any tag like <p></p> or <h1></h1>...
    <div></div> //this too
</div>
```

Comment: This is the solution I need! Thank you!

Comment: the universal selector is not mandatory

Comment: @mplungjan Yeah maybe it did not exacly answer my question but the important thing is the idea

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use:

```
    #mainDiv *:nth-child(2){
                display: none;
        }
```

The :nth-child(n) selector matches every element that is the nth child, regardless of type, of its parent, while * is a selector who selects all elements but also select all elements inside another element.

Answer (score -1):

I believe this will help you.

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <p>This is the first line </p> 
    <ul hidden> This line will be hidden</ul>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `I want to apply display:none to the second element in #mainDiv` of course means ANY second element and not by hand

Comment: Sorry but this didn't solve my problem. I want to make it dynamically such as using css or js so it would apply on any second element in #mainDiv no matter its tag. Maybe I describe my problem not clear enough but thanks for your help.

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it